# Field's Name Table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I was trying to display the field name from a database to be used in the table header to be displayed in the twig for admin section propose!

I have my database like this one

```
id | Gram | Height | Kilos |

1  | 27.1 | 126 cm | 29 kg |
```

and I want to get the field name "Gram, Height etc" and make it as table header, I was going to make a translation for this like English to Japanese and so on, "the problem is how do I get the data field name and display it like a text any advice for this on", Thank you in advance!

Code for controller

```
 /**
     * @Route("/ingredients/header-translation", name = "z_recipe_header_translation")
     * @Template("NutritionMainBundle:Admin\create\recipe\ingredients:translate-headers.html.twig")
     */
    public function headerTranslationAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $nutrients = $em->getRepository("NutritionAdminBundle:NutritionValue")->findAll();
        return array(
            'header' => $nutrients
        );
    }
```

Twig code

```
<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>header</th>
                {% for ii in 1..9 %}
                <th>language {{ii}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for i in 1..10 %}
            <tr>
                <td>header label {{i}}</td>
                {% for ii in 1..9 %}
                    <td><input type="text"/></td>
                {% endfor %}                
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Oh this is a duplicate question so sorry about that, i'll just make it as an example, The code below will be my final answer, Thank for the help!

controller code:

```
/**
     * @Route("/ingredients/header-translation", name = "z_recipe_header_translation")
     * @Template("NutritionMainBundle:Admin\create\recipe\ingredients:translate-headers.html.twig")
     */
    public function headerTranslationAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $NutritionValueField = $em->getClassMetadata('NutritionAdminBundle:NutritionValue')->getFieldNames();

        $languages = $em->getRepository("NutritionLanguageBundle:Language")->findAll();

        $form = $this->createForm(new NutritionValueType());
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        return array(
            'header' => $NutritionValueField,
            'languages' => $languages,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        );
    }
```

For my Twigs display

```
 <table class="table" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>header</th>
                {% for languages in languages %}
                <th>{{languages.langLabel}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for header in header %}
            <tr>
                {% if  header == 'NDB_NO'%}
                    {#do nothing#}
                {% else %}
                <td>{{ header|replace({'_':' '}) }}</td>
                {% for languages in languages %}
                    <td><input id="{{header}}_{{ languages.id }}" type="text" value="{{header|replace({'_':' '})}}"/> </td>
                {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </t
```

body>

Comment: Show code. It's hard to help you without seeing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the database information schema:

```sql
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'databasename' 
AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'tablename';
```

Comment: It's my first time to encounter something like this i look on to it thank you

Comment: Wow its working thank you very much I just try to convert it to symfony

Comment: You mean try to convert it to `Doctrine`

Comment: Ya but already found it how! Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

use sql sentence:desc tablename;